# Pages Image size

Tags: catalina, pages

I have a png image which is 354 * 367 pixels and Preview shows Image DPI: 300 pixel/inch

When I import into Pages 10.3.5 it appears to be 12.49 * 12.95 cm

I would expect this to be 1.18 in (30 mm) wide

It is not difficult to resize but **WHY** does Pages resize the image?

The image in Question was by email, resized in Preview and inserted into a Pages document using the Media/Choose icon.

I re-downloaded the image, and checked in XnViewMP which shows:-
1638 * 1698
Print size: 13.87x14.38 cm, 5.46x5.66 inches

I imported this into Pages and it is 16.4 * 17 cm but when I ticked *Original Size* it becomes 57.78 * 59.9 cm !

Comment: There's a lot of missing details to be able to answer this question.  Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @Allan No I don't have ImageMagick, although I can't see why this would be relevant.

Comment: It's to get more details about the PNG image file.  There's additional attributes like print size, canvas size, geometry, etc.  Also, PNGs aren't calculated in inches - always metric.  Getting this info can help extrapolate why Pages is resizing like that.

Comment: That makes a little bit more sense - 1638x1698 at 118 pixels per cm (300DPI / 2.54 ≅ 118) is 13.87x14.38cm.  The question becomes is that the geometry of the image or the full canvas? Pages may be resampling it at 96 or 72 DPI (screen and print resolutions), but what they are re-sampling is still up in the air.